# wine cannot find L "C:/windows/system32/plugplay.exe

Tags: wine

I'm running Wine1.2.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid). In my file manager, I can get to the `/.wine/drive_c` folder, so I know it exists in my file system. However, when I open the Wine Configuration window (either via `apps/wine/configuration` or via terminal (**winecfg**), on the Drives tab it shows

- C: `../drive_c`
- D: `/media` UDISK
- (and a few other drives).

However, the C drive 'browse' button is greyed out, so I cannot link Wine to this drive, which in fact does appear in my file system.

When I try to bring up the wine configure page or the `../drive_c` file in terminal I get the message:

```
wine cannot find L "C/windows/system/32/plugplay.exe"
```

What is wrong and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That's normal.  If you are trying to Browse your C: drive, then do it through the applications menu.

Applications>Wine>Browse C: Drive

or open up nautilus and navigate to:

/home/user/.wine/dosdevices/c:

alternatively you could cd to the above in a terminal.

You don't actually browse the drive from the wine config though.

Comment: Thanks. It does not appear to be a problem. In Windows, P&P service in Windows was set to 'Manual' when I installed wine, and I wonder if this is why wine could not find it? As you pointed out it is not the problem. I'm having a problem w/installing windows apps via wine. When I download the windows app .exe, save to desktop, open Terminal, change directory to desktop, and enter wine USMoneyDixSunset.exe, I get "wine cannot find L "C\\windows\\system32\\USMoneyDixSunset.exe". Why does wine look there instead of on desktop?

Comment: That's the default for wine, you would actually have to give the whole path to the file. I'll show you an easier way though:                                                                  If you right click on USMoneyDixSunset.exe, there should be an open with wine option in the menu.  alternatively if you open the terminal type wine and drag the usmoney.exe into the terminal that will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy that .exe to the .wine/drive_c/windows/system32/(.exe).....
run wine (.exe).....
this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

[@Ctuchik](https://askubuntu.com/users/13018/ctuchik) posted [a solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32900/wine-cannot-find-l-c-windows-system32-plugplay-exe/1180794#comment37557_32905) that worked for me:

> That's the default for wine, you would actually have to give the whole path to the file. I'll show you an easier way though: If you right click on USMoneyDixSunset.exe, there should be an open with wine option in the menu. alternatively if you open the terminal type wine and drag the usmoney.exe into the terminal that will work as well